# How to check "suspicious message alerts" are enabled or not programmatically kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

How to check if **suspicious message alerts** are enabled or not. I am building security app with differnet other checks

I tried this but not working

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Get the TelephonyManager instance
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            // Check if the device supports the required API level
            if (telephonyManager != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                // Get the SMS suspicious activity policy
                SmsSuspiciousActivityPolicy policy = telephonyManager.getSmsSuspiciousActivityPolicy();

                // Check if suspicious message alerts are enabled
                if (policy != null && policy.isSuspiciousSmsAlertEnabled()) {
                    // Suspicious message alerts are enabled
                    // You can handle this case here
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Suspicious message alerts are enabled");
                } else {
                    // Suspicious message alerts are not enabled
                    // You can handle this case here
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Suspicious message alerts are not enabled");
                }
            }
        }
```

I wonder if I can get the setting value from where I can know if this setting is enabled or not.

For ex :
Settings.canDrawOverlays(this.context)